# List gets emptied when having multiple statements?

Tags: javascript

I know the title seems a little oddly described, but not really sure how to cover the problem otherwise :)

Anyway, in Chrome console,  I am executing the following code:

```
var ids = [];
//Initialize ids
fetchIds("hamburgers", {
                success: function(e) {
                    _.each(e, function(e) {
                        _.each(e.el, function(e) {
                            ids.push(e.ei);
                        })
                    }),
                    function() {};
                }
            });
```

This works just great and when I type `ids` in the console, it contains 5 elements. However, if I add ANY subsequent statements, `ids` is emptied? For instance, if I add a simple log:

```
var ids = [];
//Initialize ids
fetchIds("hamburgers", {
                success: function(e) {
                    _.each(e, function(e) {
                        _.each(e.el, function(e) {
                            ids.push(e.ei);
                        })
                    }),
                    function() {};
                }
            });
console.log(ids.length);
```

This outputs 0, as if `ids` contained no elements, and if I try to use `ids` in any subsequent statement, it is considered to be empty? Why is this?

Comment: It certainly should not happen like this. Can you try consoling before additional statement. Also I see a "," instead of ";" before additional statement which should be corrected. Although it doesn't make any diff.

Comment: It works when I run the statements separately. But I have always just executed multiple statements at once - it would be quite cumbersome :/

Comment: You edited the question and now both code sample are same. Can you look into that one more time? Also I am asking if you are right console if you do it in success handler itself

Comment: Does `fetchIds` contain an async process? Like an AJAX call? If so, the outside script will reach the `console.log(...)` statement before the `success` callback is executed.

Comment: What you're doing in the second execution is just essentially `var ids = [];
setTimeout(function(){ids.push(1);}, 2000);
console.log(ids.length);` which would always return 0 all the time because you did emptied the list.

Comment: It would be **very** useful if you provide the structure of the `fetchIds` function, and tell whether you can change it at will.

Comment: @Forty3 Thank you! That was indeed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the function `fetchIds` is an asynchronous function. put `console.log(ids.length);` inside `success` function